# Pushsharp not working as a windows service

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I want to use Pushsharp for sending push notifications on ios devices. So I made a simple windows forms program for sending notifications on my device. I store my apns certificate in local certificate store. Program works great and notification arrives but when I use this code for work in windows service it doesn't work. There aren't any events from pushbroker and I really don't know how to fix this. I give necessary permissions to read certificate from store to user who launch the service.

Comment: there are errors? which identity is rinnung the service?

Comment: Special user was created to run the service, which have necessary permissions to read certificate

Comment: There are no any errors in Event Log or anywhere

Comment: just for exclude permission problems you can try to execute the service as administrator, to read the certificate is not the unique requirement, for example can you user access to network?

Comment: Yes. The user can access network. Furthermore if I launch windows forms app with the same user, same code it works perfectly

Comment: Fixed by migrating to new version of Pushsharp, it works perfectly